# easiest way to fetch specific column data from mysql in php (special case)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to wirte a small php file, which will convert a results from mysql into a given XML template , on a production site.So what i did (before i knew how the site DB is constructed), i've written a very small mock DB with one table and tested my script, and it seemed to work , here is a sniplet from the table and the script

```
+----+---------------+----------------------------+--------+
| id | house         | time_cr                    | price  |
+----+---------------+----------------------------+--------+
|  1 | Villa_Niki    | 2015-01-13 13:23:56.543294 | 25000  |
|  2 | toni          | 2015-01-13 13:24:31.133273 | 34000  |
|  3 | kolio         | 2015-01-13 13:26:06.720740 | 10000  |
|  4 | aldomirovvtxi | 2015-01-13 13:26:24.226741 | 100000 |
+----+---------------+----------------------------+--------+
```

then the script fetched the data into the XML ,quite straightforward

```
$kol=$xml->addChild('realty');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


 $kol->addChild('id',$row["id"]);
 $kol->addChild('creation-date',$row["time_cr"]);
 $kol->addChild('last-update-date',$row["time_cr"]);
 $kol->addChild('url','leva');
 $kol->addChild('bldtype',$row["house"]);
  ........
```

so just using the fetch_array and then using the column indexes and looping was fine

yesterday i have opened the database on the Site, and it turned out that they put all the information not in a separate column, like for example separate column for City, State, etc. but instead they put all the information in a single column ,like this:

[image]

so is there a simple way to make it work in this case, like for a given specific listingsdb_id, to fetch the Street into the street XML tag , Area into the area XML tag etc ? All suggestions are welcome, thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was a poorly designed database. If I were you I would re-design the database after you extract the fields/data into your XML file.

I don't have PHP/MySQL/PHPMyAdmin running on this linux distro right now so I can't really write code to help you, plus I need to sleep. Maybe I will tomorrow. I have an idea in my head how I would solve the problem, but I'm having trouble expressing it as an algorithm for extracting data from these types of poorly designed databases.

You'll probably need to query the ID field for the lowest and highest values and set variables $start, $id (current pointer), $finish. Then have something like this:

```
  for ($id = $start; $id <= $finish; $id++) {
      while ($row->id = $id) {
          $array[$id][$field] = $row->field;
          $array[$id][$field][$value] = $row->value;
          $row->nextRow();
      }
  }
```

This is just pseudo code... I'm going to bed.

---

Let me just point out that you're using the old MySQL PHP API. Use MySQLi... or better yet, use PDO.

**Here are the docs for PDO:** [PDO Documentation - PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**and for for MySQLI:** [PDO Documentation - PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: i know that, but i am looking for the function or the concept to accomplish what i need, going to PDO functions then is formality

Comment: Well, I find it a bit strange that you wouldn't just start with PDO, it would save you some time. I find your original post a little hard to understand as it looks like the database is poorly designed. I'm not sure if english is your first language or not, but could you explain how the database is designed and what data it is that you need to pull from the database?

Please specify in terms of tables, records (rows, tuples), and fields (columns). If you could write up some mock SQL code to let us know how the DB is constructed that would be helpful.

Comment: hi Charles, sorry for the bad explanation, the DB was designed from a different team.What i need is for each ID(or listingsdb_id as in screenshot), i need to pull each column box into a separate XML tag.For example for id 579 (in the above screen) i want to put the 'state' into the State tag into the XML which i create, then put the StateRU into a "stateRu" tag.Now if State, StateRU, Mesto, Mesto2 etc where all separate columns, then i just can extract the information with $row["StateRU"],$row["Mesto"],$row["Mesto2"] etc

Comment: i added one more Screenshot , what i missed is that there is a third column 'listingsdbelements_field_value ,where the information which i need is stored, so i need for example to extract the information from listingsdbelements_field_value which corresponds for listingsdb_id =579  for listingsdb_field_name 'Street' , but as the db has like 700 ids, i want to do it in one go for all fields in the column